# How do I group the data received from SQL server

Tags: c#, linq

This is the data I am receiving from the SQLServer

```
+--------+--------------+
| Role   | DocumentType |
+--------+--------------+
| Admin  | Z24          |
| Admin  | Z25          |
| User   | Z24          |
| User   | Z25          |
| DocUser| Z26          |
| Admin  | Z26          |
| User   | Z26          |
| Admin  | Z27          |
+--------+--------------+
```

I want to store the above data in a list as below using C#

```
Admin - Z24, Z25, Z26, Z27
User - Z24,Z25, Z26
DocUser - Z26
```

Can someone help me?

Here is a similar example

```
class Document
{
    public string DocType { get; set; }
    public string DocName { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var docs = new List<Document>();
      docs.Add(new Document { DocType = "Main", DocName = "A", Value = 1 });
      docs.Add(new Document { DocType = "Main", DocName = "B", Value = 2 });
      docs.Add(new Document { DocType = "Main", DocName = "C", Value = 3 });
      docs.Add(new Document { DocType = "Main", DocName = "D", Value = 4 });
      docs.Add(new Document { DocType = "Main1", DocName = "D", Value = 4 });
      docs.Add(new Document { DocType = "Main1", DocName = "D", Value = 4 });
      var groupedData = docs.GroupBy(d => d.DocType).Select(group => group.ToList()).ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have a look at linq's `GroupBy`

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: I did..but did not get it

Comment: Then please post what you've tried, explain what isn't working about it and what you tried so to solve it :)

Comment: @Ravi: Include that code, Let's have a look for fix

Comment: I am not able to add my code. It says comment is long by 227 characters

Comment: You should add it to the question itself. Also make sure to add only relevant parts

Comment: If you want to group your data where is your `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve only some of the columns then use the following overload:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(key => key.Role, element => element.DocumentType);
```

Otherwise you can also use this projection:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(key => key.Role)
                 .Select(g => new {
                     Role = g.Key,
                     Documents = g.Select(i => i.DocumentType)
                 });
```

Comment: @Ravi - for next question remember posting what you have tried for the specific question. That way it won't get all these downvotes

Comment: Sure. This was the first time I have asked a question. Will keep that in mind for the next time. :)

Comment: @Ravi - I know :) that is why I gave a hard time before posting the answer. You may want to look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)